# Write row by row from/to stream using ClosedXML?

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

Using ClosedXML, (how) is it possible to write a workbook via streaming (e.g. row by row)  instead of having all data in memory and then writing it at once?

Comment: You can't. You can using OpenXml with limitations due to the nature of the file format.